How does a residential storage tank water heater maintain water level?
How does a residential storage tank water heater maintain its water level?
This seems like a simple question, and I would expect to see two float valves, one at the bottom to prevent the heater from turning on if the tank is empty, and one at the top to stop incoming water if the tank is full.
But I can't seem to find a simple explanation of how it works in practice.

do you mean a typical home hot water heater?  An industrial tank maintains level probably via a level controller

Please explain what a storage tank water heater is. Is it open to atmosphere, or is it pressurized by the feed line.

This is the standard residential cylindrical hot water heater. I misunderstood how it works -- which is why I asked the question. Thanks!

This is an expansion of fred_dot_u's answer.
The hot water tank is a closed system. Cold water enters the tank at the bottom (The actual connection may be at the top, but there is an internal pipe feed to the bottom) and exits from the top of the tank. This is of course because hot water rises and collects at the top of the tank.
When the tank is first filled it is usual to open one of the hot taps to allow the air in the tank to escape. Once all the air is purged from the tank and the hot water lines and the hot taps are closed no more water can enter the tank.
When a hot tap is opened it is the mains pressure of cold water entering the bottom of the tank that forces the hot water to exit from the top of the tank (This arrangement also reduces mixing of incoming cold water with outgoing hot water). When the hot water tap is closed no more cold water can enter the tank.
There is no need for any float valve.
Regarding your other point, Do not turn on the power to the water heater until the tank is full. Is one of the instructions in the installation information.
As Fred mentioned, there are two thermostats in a hot water tank. One of them is for the normal control of water temperature, the other is a safety device that trips if the water gets too hot. This safety thermostat has to be reset manually after the faulty control thermostat has been replaced. The other safety device is mechanical, a TP valve (temperature and pressure release valve.) If you want to know what happens if both of these are circumvented see this Mythbusters video. (DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME!)

Other than adding the caution about turning on the heater after the tank is full and the reference to a safety valve, how is this answer not a simple re-phrasing of my answer?

@fred_dot_u On re-reading your answer I realize I didn't add as much as I'd thought - except that there's no need for a low level cutoff.

Ah -- ok, so there's no changes in overall water level, but rather the relative decrease in density of hot water ensures that the newly-heated water is available at the top. And usage of hot water from the tank allows cold water to flow in at the bottom?

Rather it's the pressure of cold water entering at the bottom that forces the hot water to exit at the top. If you close the cold water feed to the tank, nothing will flow out when you open the hot faucet.

@DanielHatton As far as I can find, the older hot water systems (from Victorian times) were "coppers" a large container that had to be filled by hand and which were heated by coal. https://www.1900s.org.uk/copper-water-heater.htm The house I grew up in in England was built  in the 50's and had a sealed hot water tank off the upstairs bathroom which could be heated by a coal boiler in the kitchen or by an electric element. Cold water to the house came from an open galvanized tank in the attic which did have a float valve to maintain water level. https://www.1900s.org.uk/1940s50s-boiler.htm

Starting with an empty tank, the house plumbing is connected. Cold water source is provided to the appropriate fitting on the tank. Additionally, hot water exit is connected to those pipes installed in the wall, slab or crawl space as warranted.
When the source is opened, the tank begins to fill. In so doing, the air in the tank becomes compressed. This is addressed by opening the farthest from the tank hot water tap. It isn't completely necessary, but it reduces the spitting and sputtering when hot water is requested at the taps.
Once the air is released, supply water pressure is throughout the system, including the tank.
There is no exit for the hot water, hence no additional cold water will be provided to the tank.
The typical water heater uses one or two thermostats to regulate the heater element(s). If some hot water is used, the incoming replacement cold water will trigger the heater at a preset level, bringing the tank temperature to the desired level.
The above is a description of a nominally closed system. Your question appears to carry the overhead of an open system, which is not typical.

I'd add just one point to @fred_dot_u's excellent answer.
In most modern systems, there's actually a second tank, that's connected to the cold water coming into the hot water heater.
It deals with a fairly obvious problem: when you fill a hot water heater, the water going into it is cold. As the water gets hot, it expands. Exactly what happens then depends on the rest of the plumbing.

It might just "push" hot water back into the incoming cold-water pipe (which can then lead to hot water coming of what are supposed to be cold-water taps, among other undesirable results).
You might have a check value to prevent that, in which case the pressure in the tank increases.

The second tank is meant to hold this "extra" water as the water expands inside the heater. It'll typically be a pretty small tank (e.g., around 3-5 gallons for typical residential use). Inside, it'll have a bladder full of air at something like 30-40 PSI--high enough that as cold water is flowing into the heater, very little of it stays in the tank. But when the water expands, the increased pressure allows the water to flow into that tank, and stay there until the pressure is released (or reduced, anyway).
Here's a diagram from Amtrol, one of the vendors that sell these:

https://www.amtrol.com/
